# Android Layout setVisibility not applied

Tags: android, android-layout

so i have this xml layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#fff"
    android:orientation="vertical" >



    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/screen"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="#fff"
            android:orientation="vertical" >


           <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/ltitle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0"
                android:background="#4c4c4c"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                    android:paddingTop="5dp"
                    android:text="TARIFICATIONS VERS LE "
                    android:textColor="#f7f7f7" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/title"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
                    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                    android:paddingTop="5dp"
                    android:text="MAROC "
                    android:textColor="#fda02c" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/recherche2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_weight="0"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:paddingRight="15dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/icon_recherche_input" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </FrameLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/search"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:visibility="invisible" >


        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#2d2d2d"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="5dp" >

            <AutoCompleteTextView
                android:id="@+id/autoCompleteTextView1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/recherche"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="Search"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                android:paddingLeft="30dp"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:textColor="#cacaca"
                android:textColorHint="#cacaca"
                android:textSize="@dimen/recherche" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/autoCompleteTextView1"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:src="@drawable/icon_recherche_input" />
        </RelativeLayout>


    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

when i click on the imageview "recherche2" to make the layout "search" visible, nothing happens

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.recherche2:
        if (!(Boolean) recherche2.getTag()) {
            recherche2.setTag(true);
            search.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            screen.getForeground().setAlpha(100);
        } else {
            recherche2.setTag(false);
            search.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            screen.getForeground().setAlpha(0);
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

by the way the foreground changes, but the layout still invisible.

if anyone has a clue of what's going on, it will be much appreiated,
thank you

Comment: Does it show in the editor if you set it to `visible`? Also, `RelativeLayout` doesn't have an `orientation` property.

Comment: Did you set an OnClickListener to your ImageView?

Comment: Although this might not be fixing your problem: your call to `setAlpha()` is wrong, max value is 1, see [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setAlpha%28float%29)

Comment: Open up that layout file in an xml graphical editor to make sure that the search layout isn't pushed off the screen by the other layouts

Comment: Are you dealing with Animation somwhere in that code? I had the same problem when I dealt with visibility animations.

Comment: @codeMagic: it was a linear layout, but it's fine though

Comment: PhilippJahoda: yes the listener is on the imageview, it's OK because the foreground changes
JohnnyZ: i did, and actualy when i set the layout to visible, it is visible
avalancha: no the actual max is 255 i believe
DoctororDrive: no there is no animation
thank you all

Comment: @user2427819 No, you have `orientation` in your root `layout` which is a `RelativeLayout` according to what you posted. Not the problem just an FYI

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me you shouldn't be setting the foreground of the `screen` layout, but the background instead.

Also, you should probably call `postInvalidate()` on your `screen` layout after the switch just to ensure it redraws as a result of the click.

Comment: no luck, didn't work, the foreground is changing but there is no layout visible